# Applications icon(application menu) in left (which is default) is not showing in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, python, icons

Recently, I downloaded python 3.9 in my ubuntu and replaced it with python 3.8 but after that I don't know what happened many of the applications got uninstalled(like pycharm, vmware etc) and the side menu bar is also not visible.
**Terminal was also converted into XTERM.**

The icon size in appearance setting is showing 0(which is stucked).

Here are the screenshots of my output:-
[No side manu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCgd9.jpg)
[Icon size is stuck at 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyuCx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the default python version of your system = breaking your system.

Try the command `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal`. It may restore the correct files to your system. If that fails, then you will need to reinstall the system.